# navigating through hyperlink with value to other view

Tags: javascript, html, devextreme

I am trying to pass Account Number(100001) through hyperlink to a new page where I want to show it in page-load as an alert, which I am not able to accomplish.
Can someone please help me with this?

```
<div class="list-item">
    <a class="hyperlink" id="hyper" href="#bankedit">Add a bank account >></a>
</div>
```

Here `#bankedit` is a new page where I want the account number

Comment: Provide more of your code where you show what you've tried so far, and where it fails. SO is not the place to ask for tutorials etc. without showing any effort of your own.

Comment: If the href is going to a seperate url, you're going to need to use parameters.

Here is a decent link describing it: http://www.xul.fr/javascript/parameters.php

And use javascript to capture that parameter on the other page.

However, I must recommend using something with more privacy...As an account number, depending on the situation, could be sensitive information.

Comment: pass it as url param then access params using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Everyone for the quick and helpful response I am able to solve it.

I used `href="#bankedit?AccountNumber=10000"` 
to pass the value and `var accountNumber = params.AccountNumber;` to retrieve in other view